# How to place a div under a form

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to place a div under a form but I can't. I have set both elements position:relative but the div is not even displayed. It is only displayed when I set the div's position to absolute but if I do that there is a white space between the form and the div that I don't want. I find all the css positioning very confusing. Thank you very much for your time.

EDIT: I have no code on the div because it is a map I have created using Google Maps API in JavaScript.

```js
// Set user's current location on map and hide irrelevant elements
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $("table").hide();
  $("button").hide();
  $(available).hide();
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            var pos = {
              lat: position.coords.latitude,
              lng: position.coords.longitude
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                zoom:14,
                center: pos
            });

  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  new AutocompleteDirectionsHandler(map);
});
```

```css
.DestinationSearch {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding-top: 20px;
  background-color: rgb(70, 144, 255);
  font-size: 16px;
  height: 25%;
  width: 100%;
}

#map {
  position: relative;
  height: 76%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<form action="{{ url_for('search') }}" method="post" class="DestinationSearch" id="search">
  <i class='fas fa-arrow-left arrow' id="arrow" onclick="location.href='http://127.0.0.1:5000/Drunkfy/Home'"></i>
  <i class='fas fa-car car'></i>
  <i class='fas fa-house-user house'></i>
  <i class='fas fa-long-arrow-alt-down vertical' style='font-size:24px'></i>
  <input type="text" id="origin-input" class="boxes" placeholder="Pickup Location" title="Choose your pickup location"><br><br>
  <input type="text" id="destination-input" class="boxes" placeholder="Destination" title="Choose your destination"><br><br>
  <button type="submit" disabled style="display: none" aria-hidden="true"></button>
  <input id="searchbtn" type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: please reproduce this in a web snippet in your question

Comment: In this instance, you can use `height: 76vw;` instead of `height: 76%;`.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably set some parameters with css for the #map div like

```css
#map {
  position:relative;
  height: 76%;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 60%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.DestinationSearch {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding-top: 20px;
  background-color: rgb(70, 144, 255);
  font-size: 16px;
  height: 25%;
  width: 100%;
}

#map {
  position: absolute;
  clear: inherit;
  display:inline;
  height: 76%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<form action="{{ url_for('search') }}" method="post" class="DestinationSearch" id="search">
  <i class='fas fa-arrow-left arrow' id="arrow" onclick="location.href='http://127.0.0.1:5000/Drunkfy/Home'"></i>
  <i class='fas fa-car car'></i>
  <i class='fas fa-house-user house'></i>
  <i class='fas fa-long-arrow-alt-down vertical' style='font-size:24px'></i>
  <input type="text" id="origin-input" class="boxes" placeholder="Pickup Location" title="Choose your pickup location"><br><br>
  <input type="text" id="destination-input" class="boxes" placeholder="Destination" title="Choose your destination"><br><br>
  <button type="submit" disabled style="display: none" aria-hidden="true"></button>
  <input id="searchbtn" type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
<div id="map"></div>
```